# Using Depends() for global constants in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

I was researching implementations of stable FastAPI applications and found Safir project which provides global HTTP client as a dependency using Depends()

Here on the page for Safir project on which they suggest to do so:
https://safir.lsst.io/user-guide/http-client.html#using-the-httpx-asyncclient

and the dependency code itself:
https://github.com/lsst-sqre/safir/blob/main/src/safir/dependencies/http_client.py

What is the benefits of using Depends() in this case?
Is there a significant difference from direct usage of dependency? For example:

```py
from safir.dependencies.http_client import http_client_dependency


http_client = http_client_dependency()


@routes.get("/")
async def get_index() -> Dict[str, Any]:
    response = await http_client.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
    return await response.json()
```

Instead of Safir example:

```py
from safir.dependencies.http_client import http_client_dependency


@routes.get("/")
async def get_index(
    http_client: httpx.AsyncClient = Depends(http_client_dependency),
) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    response = await http_client.get("https://keeper.lsst.codes")
    return await response.json()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no big difference from the functionality point of view. From other points of view it will be different:

#### The benefit of dependency injection

As explained in the docs, `dependencies` are a way of declaring a necessary condition and your app/runtime will try to satisfy it before evaluating the function. See the official docs https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/ for further information.

#### Evaluation of a dependency

In `FastAPI`, as in the most general concept of a dependency, the value of the dependency is first evaluated and then passed to the function. This way, if the dependency is not met (e.g. a parameter with a value greater than x), the function will not be evaluated. On the contrary, if the dependency is used as a global variable, the function starts being evaluated and will then fail. According to how you handle errors, it may even crash your system.

#### Flexibility of a dependency

Furthermore, declaring a dependency as a parameter allows for easier unit testing. Say you are testing your paths and you need need to mock the dependency in a different way for each test. You can do it by simply calling the function and passing it the correct parameter for that test. On the other hand, using a dependency as a global variable, requires you to constantly touch the variable, leading to possible race conditions (in case of multithreading) or testing with the wrong configuration/setup/parameters.

Comment: Thank you! IMO Unit-testing seem as the only excuse for using of a Dependency in this particular case, even though I prefer to test path operators as black box tests, running application in separate process.

Comment: @Javed crafting meaningful tests is an art. Black box is good for testing how well things are integrated, but unit testing ensure that your functions produce the correct output when given a particular set of parameters

Comment: @Javed with the library mentioned, I would follow the guidelines. I haven't examined the source code, but I guess that there is some logic that first checks if the connection is available and handles the eventual error gracefully. If used outside of the dependency, it may throw exceptions that are not caught/handled correctly. The best way to discover it, is to test it!

Comment: This dependency returns cached httpx client only, hence the question :)

Comment: @Javed I just checked....there is no particular handling. It is then the same as declaring it locally at startup and accessing it. The only upside I see, is that it re-initializes the client if not ready, limiting the number of cold starts